# visual studio professional 2019 unable to start

Tags: .net, visual-studio

While starting visual studio professional getting below error

[visual studio pops up error while starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0slbU.png)

below is event viewer details

Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info:

```
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetDeclaringType(System.RuntimeType)
    at System.RuntimeType+RuntimeTypeCache.GetEnclosingType()
   at System.RuntimeType.get_DeclaringType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.AttributedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(System.Type, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery+CombinedPartDiscovery.CreatePart(System.Type, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscovery+<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<CreateDiscoveryBlockChain>b__0(System.Type)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.TransformBlock`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ProcessMessage(System.Func`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.__Canon,Int64>)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.TransformBlock`2+<>c__DisplayClass9_0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<.ctor>b__3(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.__Canon,Int64>)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.TargetCore`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ProcessMessagesLoopCore()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.TargetCore`1+<>c[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<ProcessAsyncIfNecessary_Slow>b__34_0(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

More errors from event viewer

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 16.7.30503.244, time stamp: 0x5f51e008
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4200.0, time stamp: 0x5ee03350
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x000be77f
Faulting process id: 0x1704
Faulting application start time: 0x01d68b1020f38cff
Faulting application path: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 45fa9bf7-3920-4a6a-a2b2-219401ffec92
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: have you tried to repair you Visual Studio installation? we need to know what you have done so far.

Comment: Repair, reinstall, uninstall windows 10 latest update, change installation directory, follow stack link to clear cache of vs folders.

Comment: what is the version of your Windows 10? VS 2019 needs at least Windows 10 1703. And it won't support Windows 10 "S" edition. Ensure that your machine meets this requirement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements#visual-studio-2019-system-requirements

Comment: Windows 10 pro..It was working until last Friday . Suddenly stop working but there is not VS updates.